# ConTeXt xtable split to multiple pages

Tags: context, csv, comma-separated-list, extreme-tables

How to make xtable or TABLE [split=repeat] option to work with comma-separated list?

```
\usemodule[database]

\defineseparatedlist
  [MyTable]
  [separator=comma,
   left=\bTD,right=\eTD,
   first=\bTR,last=\eTR,
   before=\bTABLE,after=\eTABLE]

\defineseparatedlist
  [MyXTable][MyTable]
  [left=\startxcell ,right=\stopxcell,
   first=\startxrow ,last=\stopxrow,
   before=\startxtable ,after=\stopxtable]

\starttext


\placetable[here,split][tab:datatable]{Massive amont of data}{
\setupTABLE[c][each][align=middle]
\setupTABLE[r][1][background=color,backgroundcolor=gray]
\startMyXTable

First   ,Second ,Data 1     ,Data 2     ,Data 3 ,Data 4 ,Data 5 ,Data 6 ,Data 7 ,Data 8 ,Data 9
1   ,394625 ,2.851      ,2.707      ,2.630  ,4.609  ,4.307  ,5.790  ,2.735  ,2.069  ,2.045
13  ,280377 ,23.333     ,22.388     ,22.241 ,9.449  ,11.771 ,13.755 ,13.514 ,12.286 ,10.347
25  ,127275 ,17.963     ,16.756     ,17.898 ,22.748 ,23.725 ,24.797 ,23.877 ,23.413 ,22.598
37  ,173245 ,29.772     ,30.780     ,30.777 ,27.568 ,29.406 ,29.218 ,30.868 ,30.267 ,29.193
49  ,77461  ,18.635     ,19.133     ,18.985 ,14.334 ,14.948 ,14.998 ,15.306 ,14.968 ,14.729
61  ,44582  ,11.183     ,11.484     ,11.367 ,7.458  ,7.804  ,7.834  ,7.225  ,7.307  ,6.906
73  ,173711 ,7.158      ,6.846      ,6.637  ,10.490 ,9.830  ,12.920 ,6.332  ,4.883  ,4.876
85  ,231063 ,72.555     ,70.377     ,69.049 ,23.014 ,28.529 ,33.178 ,32.661 ,29.759 ,24.986
97  ,116044 ,48.794     ,45.362     ,45.878 ,57.196 ,60.277 ,62.034 ,59.200 ,57.877 ,55.803
109 ,222147 ,72.967     ,75.067     ,74.892 ,74.258 ,76.767 ,78.971 ,82.254 ,81.129 ,77.810
121 ,191791 ,49.589     ,50.911     ,50.606 ,36.522 ,38.292 ,38.776 ,39.797 ,39.265 ,37.243
133 ,206017 ,23.666     ,24.317     ,24.195 ,22.769 ,23.486 ,24.034 ,22.137 ,22.391 ,21.812
145 ,47090  ,11.432     ,10.971     ,10.628 ,15.572 ,14.706 ,18.486 ,9.554  ,7.472  ,7.487
157 ,76555  ,120.052    ,117.264    ,114.334    ,36.618 ,45.123 ,52.356 ,51.536 ,46.987 ,39.572
169 ,40744  ,78.455     ,73.448     ,73.931 ,93.251 ,98.290 ,100.599    ,95.818 ,93.480 ,89.866
181 ,79771  ,115.745    ,118.116    ,118.843    ,126.154    ,130.772    ,136.233    ,140.364    ,138.342    ,132.117
193 ,89048  ,83.100     ,84.774     ,84.483 ,62.789 ,66.339 ,68.768 ,67.647 ,67.977 ,64.810
205 ,132438 ,36.102     ,36.637     ,36.872 ,39.846 ,41.428 ,43.197 ,40.998 ,40.922 ,39.524
217 ,10571  ,15.647     ,15.051     ,14.602 ,20.112 ,19.181 ,23.648 ,12.546 ,9.915  ,9.944
229 ,17287  ,164.207    ,160.962    ,156.479    ,50.182 ,61.616 ,71.321 ,70.194 ,64.020 ,54.042
241 ,10165  ,108.618    ,101.369    ,102.310    ,130.867    ,136.934    ,141.307    ,133.747    ,130.023    ,124.849
253 ,18316  ,160.606    ,163.667    ,164.474    ,183.417    ,191.530    ,199.410    ,204.880    ,201.202    ,192.656
265 ,20106  ,118.348    ,121.172    ,120.815    ,93.040 ,98.536 ,102.665    ,100.839    ,101.015    ,96.564
277 ,44771  ,52.277     ,53.649     ,53.307 ,58.894 ,61.312 ,63.966 ,61.406 ,61.447 ,58.750
289 ,2120   ,19.807     ,19.092     ,18.535 ,24.346 ,23.353 ,28.282 ,15.384 ,12.264 ,12.326
301 ,3574   ,205.160    ,201.416    ,196.055    ,63.813 ,78.101 ,90.232 ,88.721 ,80.882 ,68.470
313 ,2360   ,139.678    ,129.887    ,131.325    ,169.801    ,176.808    ,182.810    ,172.877    ,168.013    ,161.426
325 ,3907   ,207.839    ,213.406    ,212.779    ,245.760    ,258.682    ,266.596    ,273.073    ,270.188    ,259.298
337 ,3838   ,156.034    ,160.023    ,158.636    ,127.556    ,134.570    ,140.787    ,139.591    ,138.198    ,131.843
349 ,12804  ,73.411     ,75.017     ,74.693 ,78.573 ,83.021 ,85.321 ,83.206 ,83.754 ,79.983
361 ,387    ,23.928     ,23.107     ,22.449 ,28.386 ,27.469 ,32.850 ,18.137 ,14.577 ,14.639
373 ,768    ,243.546    ,238.799    ,233.053    ,77.673 ,94.578 ,109.234    ,107.117    ,97.646 ,82.828
385 ,576    ,171.258    ,159.674    ,161.108    ,211.514    ,218.463    ,227.178    ,212.795    ,206.786    ,198.975
397 ,950    ,257.901    ,265.400    ,263.914    ,314.744    ,328.262    ,339.573    ,350.404    ,344.794    ,331.186
409 ,752    ,195.331    ,201.646    ,198.753    ,166.753    ,176.056    ,184.816    ,182.848    ,181.315    ,172.178
421 ,3737   ,97.780     ,100.109    ,99.478 ,100.637    ,105.622    ,109.424    ,106.952    ,108.136    ,102.625
433 ,88     ,29.127     ,28.198     ,27.417 ,33.151 ,32.527 ,38.390 ,21.507 ,17.427 ,17.489
445 ,223    ,288.772    ,282.957    ,277.002    ,95.103 ,115.098    ,132.910    ,130.329    ,118.692    ,101.061
457 ,157    ,213.212    ,198.925    ,200.646    ,263.125    ,274.497    ,284.710    ,265.622    ,258.858    ,247.639
469 ,296    ,324.971    ,333.776    ,332.428    ,409.982    ,431.852    ,447.567    ,453.432    ,447.039    ,423.756
481 ,170    ,249.451    ,255.945    ,252.851    ,223.063    ,234.771    ,245.060    ,243.505    ,244.639    ,231.964
493 ,1397   ,132.362    ,135.757    ,134.914    ,129.674    ,137.822    ,142.931    ,140.131    ,141.140    ,134.197
505 ,305633 ,2.608      ,2.587      ,2.627  ,2.033  ,1.699  ,2.545  ,5.396  ,4.706  ,5.325
517 ,204479 ,19.464     ,20.041     ,21.556 ,4.585  ,6.346  ,8.287  ,18.538 ,17.857 ,15.779
529 ,89237  ,18.950     ,17.805     ,18.522 ,19.327 ,19.974 ,20.994 ,26.741 ,26.587 ,25.728
541 ,113779 ,32.082     ,31.891     ,30.790 ,25.089 ,26.793 ,26.643 ,33.222 ,32.760 ,31.734
553 ,44101  ,18.963     ,19.175     ,18.792 ,12.870 ,13.426 ,13.448 ,17.050 ,16.746 ,16.498
565 ,21613  ,10.910     ,11.254     ,11.203 ,6.951  ,7.254  ,7.074  ,8.124  ,8.232  ,7.753
577 ,148719 ,6.560      ,6.546      ,6.632  ,4.782  ,4.068  ,6.035  ,12.314 ,10.844 ,12.166
589 ,182954 ,62.036     ,64.404     ,67.505 ,11.264 ,15.538 ,20.198 ,44.433 ,42.889 ,37.893
601 ,87072  ,47.817     ,46.311     ,48.436 ,47.940 ,50.276 ,52.177 ,66.952 ,66.390 ,64.276
613 ,148495 ,77.463     ,77.280     ,74.962 ,66.973 ,69.435 ,71.775 ,88.837 ,88.276 ,85.062
625 ,107320 ,50.060     ,50.772     ,49.983 ,33.407 ,34.792 ,34.857 ,43.656 ,43.266 ,41.221
637 ,121235 ,23.244     ,23.866     ,23.779 ,20.707 ,21.127 ,21.483 ,24.988 ,25.322 ,24.542
649 ,41877  ,10.483     ,10.497     ,10.616 ,7.314  ,6.313  ,9.246  ,18.591 ,16.424 ,18.308
661 ,65708  ,104.324    ,108.315    ,112.224    ,18.057 ,24.647 ,31.998 ,69.752 ,67.327 ,59.662
673 ,33924  ,76.164     ,74.287     ,77.857 ,77.405 ,81.248 ,83.251 ,109.169    ,107.962    ,104.408
685 ,57427  ,123.018    ,121.686    ,119.149    ,112.858    ,117.440    ,123.100    ,152.601    ,150.876    ,145.216
697 ,50088  ,83.900     ,84.510     ,83.436 ,57.373 ,59.750 ,61.824 ,74.788 ,75.439 ,71.904
709 ,91112  ,35.660     ,36.001     ,36.221 ,35.932 ,37.116 ,38.492 ,46.255 ,46.327 ,44.623
721 ,9554   ,14.360     ,14.416     ,14.591 ,9.784  ,8.483  ,12.161 ,24.588 ,21.709 ,24.135
733 ,14670  ,143.912    ,149.457    ,153.780    ,25.077 ,33.855 ,43.827 ,94.675 ,91.284 ,81.230
745 ,8683   ,104.947    ,102.400    ,107.561    ,107.870    ,112.756    ,116.317    ,153.311    ,151.485    ,145.884
757 ,13147  ,171.186    ,168.935    ,164.943    ,164.018    ,171.822    ,178.639    ,223.071    ,221.576    ,213.500
769 ,11017  ,119.587    ,120.807    ,119.216    ,84.348 ,88.868 ,91.786 ,112.224    ,112.392    ,107.298
781 ,32426  ,51.724     ,52.823     ,52.411 ,53.029 ,54.666 ,56.548 ,69.263 ,69.790 ,67.016
793 ,2146   ,18.202     ,18.295     ,18.528 ,12.196 ,10.561 ,14.841 ,30.345 ,26.763 ,29.756
805 ,2797   ,180.857    ,187.754    ,192.471    ,32.225 ,43.183 ,55.665 ,119.239    ,114.790    ,102.532
817 ,1844   ,134.563    ,130.971    ,138.079    ,139.153    ,145.023    ,150.081    ,198.777    ,196.255    ,189.815
829 ,2712   ,221.787    ,220.684    ,213.478    ,219.760    ,230.500    ,238.857    ,299.471    ,297.481    ,288.553
841 ,1875   ,157.702    ,159.516    ,156.457    ,115.562    ,120.603    ,125.943    ,155.678    ,155.152    ,148.095
853 ,8306   ,72.343     ,73.661     ,73.256 ,70.745 ,73.590 ,75.801 ,94.246 ,95.622 ,91.240
865 ,352    ,22.013     ,22.143     ,22.447 ,14.556 ,12.580 ,17.342 ,35.994 ,31.744 ,35.108
877 ,478    ,215.639    ,223.179    ,228.875    ,39.460 ,52.429 ,67.519 ,143.498    ,137.905    ,123.495
889 ,352    ,165.080    ,160.910    ,169.561    ,171.560    ,177.902    ,184.716    ,246.047    ,244.112    ,234.049
901 ,478    ,275.837    ,274.535    ,264.922    ,279.558    ,292.680    ,303.296    ,384.414    ,380.955    ,365.993
913 ,333    ,197.509    ,201.080    ,196.106    ,149.119    ,156.488    ,164.264    ,204.346    ,204.267    ,195.041
925 ,2155   ,96.055     ,98.077     ,97.502 ,89.362 ,93.788 ,95.917 ,121.714    ,123.409    ,116.913
937 ,72     ,26.837     ,26.999     ,27.419 ,17.496 ,15.075 ,20.344 ,43.036 ,37.895 ,41.750
949 ,88     ,256.913    ,265.049    ,272.058    ,48.697 ,64.215 ,82.645 ,174.103    ,166.722    ,150.106
961 ,60     ,204.881    ,200.261    ,210.748    ,215.754    ,221.206    ,229.964    ,307.076    ,304.011    ,290.928
973 ,79     ,347.477    ,344.958    ,333.813    ,363.673    ,376.834    ,392.226    ,503.737    ,498.543    ,479.198
985 ,50     ,252.325    ,255.178    ,249.291    ,198.221    ,207.381    ,217.509    ,273.561    ,277.512    ,262.123
997 ,569    ,129.859    ,132.779    ,132.130    ,115.317    ,120.973    ,124.735    ,161.530    ,162.763    ,154.580
\stopMyXTable
}
\stoptext
```

[image: How the above code renders on my setup]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To repeat the table head you have to partition the table into head and body using `\startxtablehead` and `\stopxtablehead`:

```
\usemodule[database]

\setupxtable
  [split=yes,
   header=repeat]

\defineseparatedlist
  [CSVxtablehead]
  [separator=comma,
   left=\startxcell,right=\stopxcell,
   first={\startxrow[background=color,backgroundcolor=gray]},last=\stopxrow,
   before=\startxtablehead,after=\stopxtablehead]

\defineseparatedlist
  [CSVxtablebody]
  [separator=comma,
   left=\startxcell,right=\stopxcell,
   first=\startxrow,last=\stopxrow,
   before=\startxtablebody,after=\stopxtablebody]

\startbuffer[table]
   \startxtable
   \startCSVxtablehead
   First   ,Second ,Data 1     ,Data 2     ,Data 3 ,Data 4 ,Data 5 ,Data 6 ,Data 7 ,Data 8 ,Data 9
   \stopCSVxtablehead
   \startCSVxtablebody
   1   ,394625 ,2.851      ,2.707      ,2.630  ,4.609  ,4.307  ,5.790  ,2.735  ,2.069  ,2.045
   13  ,280377 ,23.333     ,22.388     ,22.241 ,9.449  ,11.771 ,13.755 ,13.514 ,12.286 ,10.347
   25  ,127275 ,17.963     ,16.756     ,17.898 ,22.748 ,23.725 ,24.797 ,23.877 ,23.413 ,22.598
   37  ,173245 ,29.772     ,30.780     ,30.777 ,27.568 ,29.406 ,29.218 ,30.868 ,30.267 ,29.193
   49  ,77461  ,18.635     ,19.133     ,18.985 ,14.334 ,14.948 ,14.998 ,15.306 ,14.968 ,14.729
   61  ,44582  ,11.183     ,11.484     ,11.367 ,7.458  ,7.804  ,7.834  ,7.225  ,7.307  ,6.906
   73  ,173711 ,7.158      ,6.846      ,6.637  ,10.490 ,9.830  ,12.920 ,6.332  ,4.883  ,4.876
   85  ,231063 ,72.555     ,70.377     ,69.049 ,23.014 ,28.529 ,33.178 ,32.661 ,29.759 ,24.986
   97  ,116044 ,48.794     ,45.362     ,45.878 ,57.196 ,60.277 ,62.034 ,59.200 ,57.877 ,55.803
   109 ,222147 ,72.967     ,75.067     ,74.892 ,74.258 ,76.767 ,78.971 ,82.254 ,81.129 ,77.810
   121 ,191791 ,49.589     ,50.911     ,50.606 ,36.522 ,38.292 ,38.776 ,39.797 ,39.265 ,37.243
   133 ,206017 ,23.666     ,24.317     ,24.195 ,22.769 ,23.486 ,24.034 ,22.137 ,22.391 ,21.812
   145 ,47090  ,11.432     ,10.971     ,10.628 ,15.572 ,14.706 ,18.486 ,9.554  ,7.472  ,7.487
   157 ,76555  ,120.052    ,117.264    ,114.334    ,36.618 ,45.123 ,52.356 ,51.536 ,46.987 ,39.572
   169 ,40744  ,78.455     ,73.448     ,73.931 ,93.251 ,98.290 ,100.599    ,95.818 ,93.480 ,89.866
   181 ,79771  ,115.745    ,118.116    ,118.843    ,126.154    ,130.772    ,136.233    ,140.364    ,138.342    ,132.117
   193 ,89048  ,83.100     ,84.774     ,84.483 ,62.789 ,66.339 ,68.768 ,67.647 ,67.977 ,64.810
   205 ,132438 ,36.102     ,36.637     ,36.872 ,39.846 ,41.428 ,43.197 ,40.998 ,40.922 ,39.524
   217 ,10571  ,15.647     ,15.051     ,14.602 ,20.112 ,19.181 ,23.648 ,12.546 ,9.915  ,9.944
   229 ,17287  ,164.207    ,160.962    ,156.479    ,50.182 ,61.616 ,71.321 ,70.194 ,64.020 ,54.042
   241 ,10165  ,108.618    ,101.369    ,102.310    ,130.867    ,136.934    ,141.307    ,133.747    ,130.023    ,124.849
   253 ,18316  ,160.606    ,163.667    ,164.474    ,183.417    ,191.530    ,199.410    ,204.880    ,201.202    ,192.656
   265 ,20106  ,118.348    ,121.172    ,120.815    ,93.040 ,98.536 ,102.665    ,100.839    ,101.015    ,96.564
   277 ,44771  ,52.277     ,53.649     ,53.307 ,58.894 ,61.312 ,63.966 ,61.406 ,61.447 ,58.750
   289 ,2120   ,19.807     ,19.092     ,18.535 ,24.346 ,23.353 ,28.282 ,15.384 ,12.264 ,12.326
   301 ,3574   ,205.160    ,201.416    ,196.055    ,63.813 ,78.101 ,90.232 ,88.721 ,80.882 ,68.470
   313 ,2360   ,139.678    ,129.887    ,131.325    ,169.801    ,176.808    ,182.810    ,172.877    ,168.013    ,161.426
   325 ,3907   ,207.839    ,213.406    ,212.779    ,245.760    ,258.682    ,266.596    ,273.073    ,270.188    ,259.298
   337 ,3838   ,156.034    ,160.023    ,158.636    ,127.556    ,134.570    ,140.787    ,139.591    ,138.198    ,131.843
   349 ,12804  ,73.411     ,75.017     ,74.693 ,78.573 ,83.021 ,85.321 ,83.206 ,83.754 ,79.983
   361 ,387    ,23.928     ,23.107     ,22.449 ,28.386 ,27.469 ,32.850 ,18.137 ,14.577 ,14.639
   373 ,768    ,243.546    ,238.799    ,233.053    ,77.673 ,94.578 ,109.234    ,107.117    ,97.646 ,82.828
   385 ,576    ,171.258    ,159.674    ,161.108    ,211.514    ,218.463    ,227.178    ,212.795    ,206.786    ,198.975
   397 ,950    ,257.901    ,265.400    ,263.914    ,314.744    ,328.262    ,339.573    ,350.404    ,344.794    ,331.186
   409 ,752    ,195.331    ,201.646    ,198.753    ,166.753    ,176.056    ,184.816    ,182.848    ,181.315    ,172.178
   421 ,3737   ,97.780     ,100.109    ,99.478 ,100.637    ,105.622    ,109.424    ,106.952    ,108.136    ,102.625
   433 ,88     ,29.127     ,28.198     ,27.417 ,33.151 ,32.527 ,38.390 ,21.507 ,17.427 ,17.489
   445 ,223    ,288.772    ,282.957    ,277.002    ,95.103 ,115.098    ,132.910    ,130.329    ,118.692    ,101.061
   457 ,157    ,213.212    ,198.925    ,200.646    ,263.125    ,274.497    ,284.710    ,265.622    ,258.858    ,247.639
   469 ,296    ,324.971    ,333.776    ,332.428    ,409.982    ,431.852    ,447.567    ,453.432    ,447.039    ,423.756
   481 ,170    ,249.451    ,255.945    ,252.851    ,223.063    ,234.771    ,245.060    ,243.505    ,244.639    ,231.964
   493 ,1397   ,132.362    ,135.757    ,134.914    ,129.674    ,137.822    ,142.931    ,140.131    ,141.140    ,134.197
   505 ,305633 ,2.608      ,2.587      ,2.627  ,2.033  ,1.699  ,2.545  ,5.396  ,4.706  ,5.325
   517 ,204479 ,19.464     ,20.041     ,21.556 ,4.585  ,6.346  ,8.287  ,18.538 ,17.857 ,15.779
   529 ,89237  ,18.950     ,17.805     ,18.522 ,19.327 ,19.974 ,20.994 ,26.741 ,26.587 ,25.728
   541 ,113779 ,32.082     ,31.891     ,30.790 ,25.089 ,26.793 ,26.643 ,33.222 ,32.760 ,31.734
   553 ,44101  ,18.963     ,19.175     ,18.792 ,12.870 ,13.426 ,13.448 ,17.050 ,16.746 ,16.498
   565 ,21613  ,10.910     ,11.254     ,11.203 ,6.951  ,7.254  ,7.074  ,8.124  ,8.232  ,7.753
   577 ,148719 ,6.560      ,6.546      ,6.632  ,4.782  ,4.068  ,6.035  ,12.314 ,10.844 ,12.166
   589 ,182954 ,62.036     ,64.404     ,67.505 ,11.264 ,15.538 ,20.198 ,44.433 ,42.889 ,37.893
   601 ,87072  ,47.817     ,46.311     ,48.436 ,47.940 ,50.276 ,52.177 ,66.952 ,66.390 ,64.276
   613 ,148495 ,77.463     ,77.280     ,74.962 ,66.973 ,69.435 ,71.775 ,88.837 ,88.276 ,85.062
   625 ,107320 ,50.060     ,50.772     ,49.983 ,33.407 ,34.792 ,34.857 ,43.656 ,43.266 ,41.221
   637 ,121235 ,23.244     ,23.866     ,23.779 ,20.707 ,21.127 ,21.483 ,24.988 ,25.322 ,24.542
   649 ,41877  ,10.483     ,10.497     ,10.616 ,7.314  ,6.313  ,9.246  ,18.591 ,16.424 ,18.308
   661 ,65708  ,104.324    ,108.315    ,112.224    ,18.057 ,24.647 ,31.998 ,69.752 ,67.327 ,59.662
   673 ,33924  ,76.164     ,74.287     ,77.857 ,77.405 ,81.248 ,83.251 ,109.169    ,107.962    ,104.408
   685 ,57427  ,123.018    ,121.686    ,119.149    ,112.858    ,117.440    ,123.100    ,152.601    ,150.876    ,145.216
   697 ,50088  ,83.900     ,84.510     ,83.436 ,57.373 ,59.750 ,61.824 ,74.788 ,75.439 ,71.904
   709 ,91112  ,35.660     ,36.001     ,36.221 ,35.932 ,37.116 ,38.492 ,46.255 ,46.327 ,44.623
   721 ,9554   ,14.360     ,14.416     ,14.591 ,9.784  ,8.483  ,12.161 ,24.588 ,21.709 ,24.135
   733 ,14670  ,143.912    ,149.457    ,153.780    ,25.077 ,33.855 ,43.827 ,94.675 ,91.284 ,81.230
   745 ,8683   ,104.947    ,102.400    ,107.561    ,107.870    ,112.756    ,116.317    ,153.311    ,151.485    ,145.884
   757 ,13147  ,171.186    ,168.935    ,164.943    ,164.018    ,171.822    ,178.639    ,223.071    ,221.576    ,213.500
   769 ,11017  ,119.587    ,120.807    ,119.216    ,84.348 ,88.868 ,91.786 ,112.224    ,112.392    ,107.298
   781 ,32426  ,51.724     ,52.823     ,52.411 ,53.029 ,54.666 ,56.548 ,69.263 ,69.790 ,67.016
   793 ,2146   ,18.202     ,18.295     ,18.528 ,12.196 ,10.561 ,14.841 ,30.345 ,26.763 ,29.756
   805 ,2797   ,180.857    ,187.754    ,192.471    ,32.225 ,43.183 ,55.665 ,119.239    ,114.790    ,102.532
   817 ,1844   ,134.563    ,130.971    ,138.079    ,139.153    ,145.023    ,150.081    ,198.777    ,196.255    ,189.815
   829 ,2712   ,221.787    ,220.684    ,213.478    ,219.760    ,230.500    ,238.857    ,299.471    ,297.481    ,288.553
   841 ,1875   ,157.702    ,159.516    ,156.457    ,115.562    ,120.603    ,125.943    ,155.678    ,155.152    ,148.095
   853 ,8306   ,72.343     ,73.661     ,73.256 ,70.745 ,73.590 ,75.801 ,94.246 ,95.622 ,91.240
   865 ,352    ,22.013     ,22.143     ,22.447 ,14.556 ,12.580 ,17.342 ,35.994 ,31.744 ,35.108
   877 ,478    ,215.639    ,223.179    ,228.875    ,39.460 ,52.429 ,67.519 ,143.498    ,137.905    ,123.495
   889 ,352    ,165.080    ,160.910    ,169.561    ,171.560    ,177.902    ,184.716    ,246.047    ,244.112    ,234.049
   901 ,478    ,275.837    ,274.535    ,264.922    ,279.558    ,292.680    ,303.296    ,384.414    ,380.955    ,365.993
   913 ,333    ,197.509    ,201.080    ,196.106    ,149.119    ,156.488    ,164.264    ,204.346    ,204.267    ,195.041
   925 ,2155   ,96.055     ,98.077     ,97.502 ,89.362 ,93.788 ,95.917 ,121.714    ,123.409    ,116.913
   937 ,72     ,26.837     ,26.999     ,27.419 ,17.496 ,15.075 ,20.344 ,43.036 ,37.895 ,41.750
   949 ,88     ,256.913    ,265.049    ,272.058    ,48.697 ,64.215 ,82.645 ,174.103    ,166.722    ,150.106
   961 ,60     ,204.881    ,200.261    ,210.748    ,215.754    ,221.206    ,229.964    ,307.076    ,304.011    ,290.928
   973 ,79     ,347.477    ,344.958    ,333.813    ,363.673    ,376.834    ,392.226    ,503.737    ,498.543    ,479.198
   985 ,50     ,252.325    ,255.178    ,249.291    ,198.221    ,207.381    ,217.509    ,273.561    ,277.512    ,262.123
   997 ,569    ,129.859    ,132.779    ,132.130    ,115.317    ,120.973    ,124.735    ,161.530    ,162.763    ,154.580
   \stopCSVxtablebody
   \stopxtable
\stopbuffer

\starttext
\placetable[here,split][tab:datatable]{Massive amont of data}{
   \getbuffer[table]
   }

\stoptext
```

[image]